# conda init gives me "no action taken"

Tags: 19.04, anaconda

I'm getting this while installing anaconda on ubuntu 19.04
[image: Im getting this while installing anaconda on ubuntu 19.04]

Comment: make sure you have root permission.
type in terminal command  su - and it will ask you root password and then try to install.

Comment: @JackyChan: `anaconda` does not need `root` priviledges when installed in the home directory of a user.

Comment: Did you upgrade `anaconda` or just did a fresh install? Maybe nothing has to be done by ` conda init`? It looks like the `conda` environment is set up already. Does `conda activate <environment>` work?

Comment: I think you done everything. Then just run the command anaconda-navigator in terminal

Comment: Please copy and paste logs in text (or type in), do not post an image for text output.

Answer (score 10):

While this does not try to fix this problem, rather helps as a workaround when I want to activate an env.

```
$ source ~/anaconda3/bin/activate <env_name>
```

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem. Previously I had anaconda 2 but I removed to install anaconda 3. After installing anaconda 3 and using conda init I got the same error message, as I solved it. Enter your `.bashrc`:

```
gedit ~/.bashrc
```

Identify the following lines in the `.bashrc` file and delete them:

```
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup = "$ ('/ home / spidey / anaconda3 / bin / conda' 'shell.bash' 
'hook' 2> / dev / null)"
if [$? -eq 0]; then
    eval "$ __ conda_setup"
else
    if [-f "/home/spidey/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"]; then
        . "/home/spidey/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH = "/ home / spidey / anaconda3 / bin: $ PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

**Explanation:**
Since previously you already had an anaconda installation, the conda `init command` did not modify anything because it detected that you had already made changes to the `.bashrc` file.

Answer (score 3):

Try By Using *anaconda-navigator*:

activate conda:

```
$ source ~/anaconda3/bin/activate root
```

Launch conda:

```
$ anaconda-navigator
```

If you want to launch JupyterNotebook simply run

```
jupyter notebook
```

Comment: This works for me

Answer (score 1):

`source ~/.bashrc` or `source ~/.bash_profile` should work

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand this, `conda init [shell]` is used to initiate a specific shell utilized when executing command-line `conda` commands. Not specifying one will default it to bash, which I'm guessing is what you already use here—since this is the output.

More information can be found by using the `[-h]` flag:

```
$ conda init -h
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```
conda activate
jupyter notebook
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

`/opt/conda/bin/conda init zsh`

as it states here (from `/opt/conda/bin/conda init -h` )

> positional arguments:   shells         One or more shells to be
> initialized. If not given, the default value is 'bash' on unix and
> 'cmd.exe' on Windows. Use the '--all' flag to initialize
> all shells. Currently compatible shells are {bash, fish, powershell, tcsh, xonsh, zsh}

This is weird because I did not have this problem before while setting up another server. But anyway it is clear that you need to specify the `shell` (which is `zsh` here), otherwise `conda` will pick up `bash` as default shell.